# Can we determine the chromatic number of the union of two graphs

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, coloring

***Question:***

> Let $G_1=(V_1,E_1)$ be a graph when his chromatic number is 7, and let $G_2=(V_2,E_2)$ when his chromatic number is 5. Moreover, $|V_1\cap V_2|=2$. Let $G_3=(V_3,E_3)$ such that $V_3=V_1\cup V_2$. Can we determine what is the chromatic number of $G_3$?

---

$Solution.$

For this question we can look at the graphs $K_5$ and $K_7$ because they satisfy the required chromatic numbers.

We know that the graph $G_3$ is the union of both graphs, such that we have two in common vertices, so have to put $K_5$ onto one edge of $K_7$.

For example we have:

[image]

and after union we get:

[image]

so we get that the chromatic number of $G_3$ is 7.

---

Now is it correct? because I am not sure that this is correct always. I will be glad for an explanation. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry for the previous comment, I didn't read properly. I have a question with your procedure, why do you assume the two vertices that are shared by both graphs have different colors? Or why does exist an edge between them in both graphs? That doesn't have to be true in general, and it's something you've used in your example, so it's not clear how to generalize your procedure for the general case. (Not saying it doesn't work, just that you should consider those cases)

Comment: @AnilCh You right, but it doesn't actually matter. What do you say about the question itself?

Comment: Well, if your procedure doesn't work there are two options: Either you can fix the procedure and be able to generalize it to any two examples, or there are examples where the chromatic number is not $7$. Try to look first for a counterexample playing with the idea that the color of these vertices might be the same in one graph, and different in the other.

Comment: @AnilCh Like I said I don't think it is matters, because even if all the colors are the same as in $K_7$ then we will have at least 7 different colors.

Comment: I disagree, I think it matters a lot, picture this: the graph with chromatic color $7$ has the same (forced) color in the two shared vertices $v_1, v_2$. But the graph with chromatic color $5$ has an edge between these two vertices $v_1, v_2$. Which means that the union will have an edge between these two vertices, and you'd need at least eight colors for it.

Comment: @AnilCh why not 7? can you show me/ right an answer for it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a $K_9$ complete graph. Label three vertices as $\{v_1, v_2, v_3\}$ and erase the triangle of edges between them. You get a graph with chromatic number $7$. Let $V_1 \cap V_2 = \{v_1, v_2\}$. Notice that $v_1, v_2$ have to have the same color in all colorings of the graph with seven colors. Notice that if any two vertices between $\{v_1, v_2, v_3\}$ were to have a new edge, we would have a $K_8$ subgraph inside it, so the chromatic color would increase.

Now take $K_5$ as the graph with chromatic number $5$. The union of these two graphs has an edge between $v_1, v_2$. So, as said before, we have a $K_8$ subgraph inside the union, so the chromatic color must be at least $8$.

The idea behind this counterexample is: Let the graph with more colors have the same colors in the intersection, and let the other graph add edges in that intersection. These new edges force additional colors. I hope that clarifies a bit what I was saying in comments.

Comment: Yes, it is. Thanks!